# smbclient shows me my share, smbnetfs does not

Tags: networking, samba, cifs, workgroup

I have a Windows 7 share that I want to mount in my home directory. I'm using Xubuntu 14.04.3 which has the Thunar file manager.

I can use `smbclient` to see (`ls`) the share and files I wish to access. I have set up `.smb/smbnetfs.auth` as shown below (except the password is not `password` *:)* ), using values which work for `smbclient`.

`.smb/smbnetfs.conf` is rather large, but I have not changed it - it appears to be set up to use the auth file.

I have added the user to the `fuse` group.

I have changed the workgroup setting in `smb.conf` (and restarted `smbd`).

However, when I issue the command

```
smbnetfs ~/mountdir
```

all that happens is that `mountdir` contains a directory `WORKGROUP` that has no contents. There is no domain or workgroup called `WORKGROUP` on my network. The machine which has the share belongs to the `HOME` workgroup.

`smbnetfs.auth` is:

```
auth "BLACK/Black_E" "HOME/mderouss" "password"
```

`smbnetfs.conf` includes:

```
# read auth data from ~/.smb/smbnetfs.auth
include         "smbnetfs.auth"
```

`smb.conf` includes:

```
# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
   workgroup = HOME
```

I see many reports of this type in `auth.log`, but have no idea if they are relevant in any way:

```
Nov  8 01:22:00 mark-PC smbd[9241]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, problem solved.

I changed the auth file to :

auth "HOME" "mderouss" "password"

This did not solve the problem.

Then I also corrected a problem I noticed in the nmbd log ( /var/log/samba/log.nmbd ) :

```
[2015/11/08 14:27:01,  0] ../source3    /nmbd/nmbd_nameregister.c:492(register_name)
register_name: NetBIOS name MARK-HP-PRO-3120 is too long. Truncating to 
[2015/11/08 14:27:01,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_nameregister.c:492(register_name)
register_name: NetBIOS name MARK-HP-PRO-3120 is too long. Truncating to 
[2015/11/08 14:27:01,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_nameregister.c:492(register_name)
register_name: NetBIOS name MARK-HP-PRO-3120 is too long. Truncating to
[2015/11/08 14:27:24,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_become_lmb.c:397(become_local_master_stage2)
```

I changed the hostname to 'mark-lab1', and whoopee, smbnetfs now works and I have my smb network mounted where I want it :).

I think what was going on was that my hostname was ( for reasons unknown ) being truncated to nothing, although exactly how that would lead to this problem I don't know.

Cheers,
Mark